# Distribution of residuals in multinomial / ordinal logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, residuals, multinomial-distribution, ordered-logit

In simple logistic regression, the standardized residuals are assumed to be normally distributed.

Are there any such assumptions for ordinal or multinomial logistic regression?

Because in these cases, the residuals will "contain information" about other categories, can they be assumed to follow some sort of conditional distribution?

Any information on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In a simple logistic regression, the standardized residuals are distributed logit, not normal. If they were distributed normal, then it would be a simple probit regression.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was mistaken about that. However I would still like to know if a conditional logistic or normal distribution can be used, respectively, to represent the distribution of residuals in multinomial regression for logit or probit links? or is it a bad idea for some reason? I havent found much literature on residuals for this case.